# Are there allusions to The Wizard of Oz or Alice in Wonderland in the TV miniseries Godless?

Tags: reference, the-wizard-of-oz, alice-in-wonderland-2010, godless

After recently watching the Netflix Western miniseries ***Godless***, I started to notice things, especially things pertaining to the character **Alice Fletcher** (Michelle Dockery), that reminded me of both ***The Wizard of Oz*** (1939 Film + novels) and **Alice Adventures in Wonderland** (books).

**Cinematography:**
**Godless** uses **special colorization techniques**. Flashbacks tend to be in black and white with random coloring fixating on a specific object, part of the body or face, and/or landscape focusing (ie.: black and white in the foreground, color tint on a hill in the background). Sometime though it's more like a color-fading/bleeding or scenes have a bit of a color tint at times. (I wish I had more examples, but I am having trouble finding screencaps)

[image: Roy, Frank]

[image: Frank]

The film version of *The Wizard of Oz* was originally released in black and white and later re-released in technicolor. The technicolor version however chooses to have all of the Kansas scenes depicted in a sepia tint to convey a sharp contrast between **the drab farm life of rural Kansas and the whimsical colorful fantasy of Oz**.

[image: Dorothy]

**The Character Alice Fletcher:**

Obviously the name Alice might make one think of Alice from *'Alice in Wonderland'*. It's also believed that Frank L. Baum's Oz novels owes something to and may have barrowed from Lewis Carroll's **Alice Adventures in Wonderland** novels; both being about **young girls taken to a fantasy world**, where each, in their own ways, explores what it means for these young ladies to find themselves, learn responsibility, and grow up.

[image: Alice]

*Godless'* Alice Fetcher looks more iconic to how the film version depicts Dorothy being an auburn-brunette, wearing gingham on at least one occasion (the one where she tells Roy her "story"), and often wearing a braid (a signature hairstyle). She also comes to live with **3 companions** during the course the series. Her son, her mother in-law, and Roy Goode.

[image: Alice with Roy]

In addition the character tells Roy Goode about what happened to her first husband and **how she came from Baltimore to live in New Mexico**. The story itself comes off as a fantasy or a myth, and IMO conveys colors and concepts (albeit from a flashback we see it's much darker then the tale Alice tells Roy) that seem similar with the colored version of *The Wizard of Oz*. Like clouds/storms = tornado, the green cloud and water = wicked Witch of the WEST, the yellow dress/gold = yellow brick road---> the way "home", etc...

[image: Threats from Wicked Witch of the West]

> Alice: There's some lore about finding **gold** under the fence posts.
> They say that's where the old ranchers use to hide it from the Indians
> and Outlaws. Of course, I never found any myself. Never had that kind
> of luck.
>
> Roy: Do you mind me asking how the three of you ended up in this
> place?
>
> Alice: Well that's a bit of a story. I was only 17 and I came out here
> to marry the son of my father's business partner. All I knew about him
> was that his name was Henry and he was to meet me at the train
> station. He sent me a new **yellow** dress, so I'd stand out and told
> me to wear it the day I arrived so he'd know me.  On the way back from
> the station, Henry wants to take a ride around the property, show off
> his land.  "Our land", he said. After a while, the horse pulling the
> buggy starts to get antsy. **I look up and see this strange cloud.
> Black with green around the edges.** Henry says, "Looks like we got a
> bit of rain coming." Next thing we knew, the could was gone. Just
> vanished. Now the horse starts to rear in the traces. Henry helps me
> out of the wagon when I hear a rumble. I turn around and see a
> six-foot wall of water coming right at us. Henry, the horse, the buggy
> they all got washed away right in front of me. I almost did, too, but
> **my new yellow dress got hung up on some mesquite**. Saved my life. I
> wondered off for eight days in the wrong direction before I was found.

Many believe *Godless* itself is about **the invention of the myth** and turns the idea of Western myth on it's head a bit, by subverting from more often overused clichés, but yet remaining true by having some myths within it's own universe seemingly present, despite the story is somewhat a tragedy. *The Wizard of Oz* is also allegorical and one could maybe see the "The Great Flood" in this story as well as other Biblical mythos and/or philosophical constructs of what "God" is (given the title and Frank's way of thinking) in this series.

**Other factors:** *Godless* is in part not just about one women and her journey, but really several. It's somewhat a womens' survivalist story. La Belle is a place that was a mining town where a tragedy happened, where almost all the men died in mining accident, leaving the women to fend for themselves---until one day other men come to take over and mine again--Even the idea of digging for "gold", jewels, or resources of wealth are similar to things like the Yellow Brick Road & Emerald City---things that almost seem too good to be purely true...

So my question is, **are these intentional references & allusions to either *The Wizard of Oz*** and/or by extension *Alice Adventures in Wonderland*?